# play exclude dependencies

Tags: playframework

trying to exclude some spring dependencies, using the following

```
 require:
    - play
    - com.openadex.jupiter -> jupiter.protocol 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT:
          exclude:
              org.springframework -> spring-core 3.1.0.RELEASE
```

But this stills downloads spring-core when running play deps --sync

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
 require:
    - play
    - com.openadex.jupiter -> jupiter.protocol 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT:
          exclude:
              - org.springframework -> spring-core 3.1.0.RELEASE
```

Mind the '-' in front of the last line.